# Passing a querystring value as part of an ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an **ActionResult** return type inside my Controller which executes the default Index action.

```
public **ActionResult** Index(int _page, string **tabIdx**)

{

if (tabIdx == null)
                        ViewData.Add("TabIdx","0");
                    else
                        ViewData.Add("TabIdx", tabIdx);

                    **actionResult = View("Index");**

 return actionResult;

}
```

The ViewData variable is for processing inside my javascript, so you can ignore it for the purpose of this question.

What I need to do is to simply pass a querystring value for the tabIdx field in the above boldfaced line of code.

Something like View("Index") with a querystirng value appened to it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `RedirectToAction`. The URL already is set in stone after the request.

However, there might be a way to pass that value somewhere else so that it can be used without a redirect.